# function and if else javascript issue

Tags: javascript, function, validation, warnings

I am to the final step all I need to show up is success message in place of the error if both fields are filled. is it an if else?
or would i have to create a while loop? My current issue is just getting the success message to show up once both of the fields are filled. I have tried different variations of if statements but nothing has worked yet.

```js
< script >
  function login() {

    // variables for text box values
    var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("pw").value;

    // variables for error messages
    var theError = document.getElementById("error");

    // clear out error messages each time
    theError.innerHTML = "";

    if (userName == "") {
      theError.innerHTML = "please enter a username and password";
      return false;
    } else {
      theError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (password == "") {
      theError.innerHTML = "please enter a username and password";
      return false;
    } else {
      theError.innerHTML = "";
      return true
    }

  } //end function

function init() {
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = login;
}

window.onload = init; < /script>
<script>
/ / Fading in Advertisent

$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#ad").animate({
    top: '100px',
  }, (5000));


  //Closing The Advertisement
  $("#adbtn").click(function() {
    $("#ad").fadeOut(5000);
  });


  //Sliding login form
  $(".plus").click(function() {
    $("form").slideToggle(1000); // half second duration
    $(this).toggleClass("plus").toggleClass(
      "minus");
  });

});

< /script>
```

```css
<style> body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
a {
  color: blue;
}
#welcome p strong {
  color: navy;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#welcome p:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
section {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
/* main container */

#main {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0ff;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* form container */

#loginDiv {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 650px;
  top: 6px;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid navy;
}
/* paragraph that shows the text "Login" which is clicked on to display/remove the form */

#login {
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 5px 0 2px 30px;
}
#login:hover {
  background-color: rgb(110, 138, 195);
}
/*  plus sign icon for login form */

.plus {
  background: url(img_open.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
  background-color: rgb(110, 138, 195);
}
/* minus sign icon for login form */

.minus {
  background: url(img_close.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
}
/*form is hidden when the page loads */

#loginDiv form {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#loginDiv label {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}
#loginDiv input {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid navy;
}
#loginDiv input:focus {
  background-color: rgb(110, 138, 195);
  border: 2px solid navy;
}
#loginDiv input[type=button] {
  width: 100px;
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
/* ad is not shown when the page loads  */

#ad {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 330px;
  top: -500px;
  /* you can change this inbitially for viewing purposes only but be sure to set it back */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url(ad.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* close button on ad */

#adbtn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Assignment 6</title>

  <!-- video  https://youtu.be/XEoWYcolaEM -->


  <script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- main container -->
  <div id="main">
    <section id="loginDiv">
      <!-- when this is clicked on the below form should be displayed and plus sign should change to minus sign-->
      <p id="login" class="plus">Login</p>
      <form>
        <p>
          <label for="username">Username:</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="pw">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw">
        </p>
        <p>
          <input id="button" type="button" value="Submit">
        </p>

        <!-- placeholder for response if form data is correct/incorrect -->
        <p id="error"></p>
      </form>
    </section>
    <section id="welcome">
      <h1>Welcome to the Local jQuery User Group Website</h1>
      <p> <strong>Click the login button at the top of the page to login. To become a member please <a href="#">Register</a></strong> 
      </p>
      <h2>About this page layout:</h2>
      <p>The main container (parent) has 'relative' positioning so that the 'login' container can be absolutley positioned with respect to that main container. Otherwise, it would default to being absolutley positioned with respect to the window.</p>
      <p>In order for the login panel to be placed on top of the page we need to use absolute positioning, otherwise, it would move the rest of the content down as done in the FAQ assignment. Technically, absolute positioning takes that element out of the
        normal flow of the document, so that it is on top of the page. The 'ad' is also absolutely positioned to the same main container.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>This week's agenda:</h2>
      <p>There will be a live meeting this Tuesday evening from 7:00pm to 8:00pm PST using our WebEx Conferencing Software. It will be recorded! Please note that the code samples will be available on our GitHub repository.</p>
    </section>
    <footer>Copyright &copy; Local jQuery User Group</footer>

    <!--  ad which is absolutely positioned -500px from the top so you do not see it when page loads-->
    <div id="ad">
      <div id="adbtn">X</div>
    </div>

    <!-- end main container -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `if (password.length > 0 && userName.length > 0) { alert('success') }`

Comment: @adeneo thanks big time !

Comment: @snookieordie complete noob here sorry ill keep that in mind for the next post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place an `else` condition

```js
function login() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("pw").value;
  var theError = document.getElementById("error");
  //theError.innerHTML = "";//No need of this as is is being manipulated in conditions
  if (userName == "" || password == "") { //As message is same for both the inputs, || could be used
    theError.innerHTML = "please enter a username and password";
    return false;
  } else {
    theError.innerHTML = "Success!";
    return true
  }
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = login;
}

window.onload = init;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ad").animate({
    top: '100px',
  }, (5000));
  $("#adbtn").click(function() {
    $("#ad").fadeOut(5000);
  });
  $(".plus").click(function() {
    $("form").slideToggle(1000); // half second duration
    $(this).toggleClass("plus").toggleClass(
      "minus");
  });
});
```

```css
<style> body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
a {
  color: blue;
}
#welcome p strong {
  color: navy;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#welcome p:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
section {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
/* main container */

#main {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0ff;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* form container */

#loginDiv {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 650px;
  top: 6px;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid navy;
}
/* paragraph that shows the text "Login" which is clicked on to display/remove the form */

#login {
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 5px 0 2px 30px;
}
#login:hover {
  background-color: rgb(110, 138, 195);
}
/*  plus sign icon for login form */

.plus {
  background: url(img_open.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
  background-color: rgb(110, 138, 195);
}
/* minus sign icon for login form */

.minus {
  background: url(img_close.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
}
/*form is hidden when the page loads */

#loginDiv form {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#loginDiv label {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}
#loginDiv input {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid navy;
}
#loginDiv input:focus {
  background-color: rgb(110, 138, 195);
  border: 2px solid navy;
}
#loginDiv input[type=button] {
  width: 100px;
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
/* ad is not shown when the page loads  */

#ad {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 330px;
  top: -500px;
  /* you can change this inbitially for viewing purposes only but be sure to set it back */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url(ad.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* close button on ad */

#adbtn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<!-- main container -->
<div id="main">
  <section id="loginDiv">
    <!-- when this is clicked on the below form should be displayed and plus sign should change to minus sign-->
    <p id="login" class="plus">Login</p>
    <form>
      <p>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="pw">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input id="button" type="button" value="Submit">
      </p>

      <!-- placeholder for response if form data is correct/incorrect -->
      <p id="error"></p>
    </form>
  </section>
  <section id="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to the Local jQuery User Group Website</h1>
    <p> <strong>Click the login button at the top of the page to login. To become a member please <a href="#">Register</a></strong> 
    </p>
    <h2>About this page layout:</h2>
    <p>The main container (parent) has 'relative' positioning so that the 'login' container can be absolutley positioned with respect to that main container. Otherwise, it would default to being absolutley positioned with respect to the window.</p>
    <p>In order for the login panel to be placed on top of the page we need to use absolute positioning, otherwise, it would move the rest of the content down as done in the FAQ assignment. Technically, absolute positioning takes that element out of the
      normal flow of the document, so that it is on top of the page. The 'ad' is also absolutely positioned to the same main container.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>This week's agenda:</h2>
    <p>There will be a live meeting this Tuesday evening from 7:00pm to 8:00pm PST using our WebEx Conferencing Software. It will be recorded! Please note that the code samples will be available on our GitHub repository.</p>
  </section>
  <footer>Copyright &copy; Local jQuery User Group</footer>
  <div id="ad">
    <div id="adbtn">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used a little bit of a different syntax from what you posted and still got it to work 
whats the difference? else{
   theError.innerHTML = "";
     if (password.length > 0 && userName.length > 0) { 
   theError.innerHTML = "Success, please wait";
  }

Comment: Statement itself is quiet readable.. If `length` of both `username` and `password` is greater than `0` => _"success"_ else _"error message"_.. In my post, If any of `username` and `password` is `""(empty)`, show error message or _"success"_

Comment: Okay that explains it clearly for me. This is huge for me it feels like lol

Comment: @BlackRoseGoat, Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, I am not sure where do you want to show the success message, Anyway , I assumed that you want to show in "theError"  I added some changes to the js file and created a plunker link if you want to look at it live:

```js
 function login() {

    // variables for text box values
    var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("pw").value;

    // variables for error messages
    var theError = document.getElementById("error");

    // clear out error messages each time
    theError.innerHTML = "";

    if (userName === "") {
      theError.innerHTML = "please enter a username and password";
      return;
    } else {
      theError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (password === "") {
      theError.innerHTML = "please enter a username and password";
      return;
    } else {

      theError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    theError.innerHTML = "Success ";
    
    return;

  } //end function
```

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/rwaMkthf18ypC1xGRDf9?p=preview)